# Is it possible to call validation methods any time before saving the object

Tags: hibernate, activerecord, jpa, jpa-2.0

In ActiveRecord its possible to check if the state of an object is valid at a certain point in time.

```
>> foo.valid?
=> false
```

Is there a way to do something similar in JPA2, since the validation framework actually gets triggered in JPA prior to save | update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create event listeners that are triggered when different events occur, such before the entity is persisted , modified, etc.

Here's a basic usage

- create a method in your Entity bean
- annotate it with one of the @PrePersist, @PostPersist annotations
- the code in that method will be called at that (those) lifecycle events in the bean

You can also create callback-logic in separate classes and attach those listeners to entity beans via class level annotations (@EntityListeners).

There's a lot of stuff here about the order in which these listeners are called, inheriting them, etc to detail it here. Look it up.

Comment: I am aware of the validation framework, my question is will I be able to call some method to see if the object is valid at any point in time prior to saving the object. It's possible in Rails, but is it possible in JPA2?

Comment: Well if you were really aware of validation frameworks, you'd know about Java EE 6 validation API, and it's (amongst others) Hibernate Validation implementations. This guy comes with a lot of different validators which you can enable by simply annotating your fields/classes, and it let's you create your custom validators pretty easy. And finally you can ask it to validate your bean whenever you want. Really, you thought Rails had more options/libraries than Java? Really?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that it was possible to call the bean validation at any time. I have no doubts about the strength of the java validation framework and I have been using it for my lifetime and I wasn't sure about this capability.